# I have a text file of a paragraph of writing, and want to iterate through each word in Python

Tags: python

How would I do this? I want to iterate through each word and see if it fits certain parameters (for example is it longer than 4 letters..etc. not really important though).

The text file is literally a rambling of text with punctuation and white spaces, much like this posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)ing the string.

```
f = open('your_file')
for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        # do something
```

If you want it without punctuation:

```
f = open('your_file')
for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        word = word.strip('.,?!')
        # do something
```

Comment: Removing punctuation may be helpful - `for word in re.sub('[^\w]+', ' ', paragraph).split():`

Comment: I am doing exactly that right now, and for the #do something I am printing the word - but nothing is printing for some reason

Comment: Seth thanks, that helps as the files I have do have punctuation

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [`content.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 0):

```
   f = open(filename,"r");
   lines = f.readlines();
   for i in lines:
   thisline = i.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data=open("file").read().split()
for item in data:
   if len(item)>4:
      print "longer than 4: ",item
```